# C# Regex for all chars and '-'

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying all combinations that I could find on google, but nothing seems to allow me the regex for all letters and only one special charachter..

Example of what Im trying to achieve:

Something-something (accepted)

something something (accepted)

-Something(not accepted)

SomethingSomething-(not accepted)

something-something-somthing(accepted)

So as you see, I need to be able to use all letters and special char - anywhere inbetween letters. Hopefully someone knows the answer on how to achieve this.

My code:

```
private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox8.Text) || !Regex.IsMatch(textBox8.Text, @"^[A-Za-z]\-+$"))
    {
        textBox8.BackColor = Color.Red;         
    }
    else
    {
        textBox8.BackColor = Color.White;           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?:[- ][A-Za-z]+)*$
```

Check [**`here`**](https://regex101.com/r/5oVZKD/2)

Regex Breakdown

```
^ #Start of string
[A-Za-z]+ #Match alphabets
(?:[- ][A-Za-z]+)* #Match - followed by alphabets 0 or more times
$ #End of string
```

Comment: This works, but how could I also tweak it to accept something something ( with space or with -)

Comment: @Rin can you give me an example?

Comment: I think I managed to fix it myself: ^[A-Za-z]+(?:[ -][A-Za-z]+)*$

Before it accepted just: https://gyazo.com/5113039e413f0f50fb58c65713271fbf

Comment: Thanks for the help and your time! You seem to understand this deeply :D

Answer (score 1):

If you need letters before and after the hyphen:

```
[A-Za-z]+\-[A-Za-z]+
```

If you just need a hyphen and letters somewhere in the string

```
[A-Za-z]?\-[A-Za-z]?
```

Comment: It seems to work, but then it doesnt accept SomethingSomething, it has to be specifically with - in between two words, is there a way to tweak it that it accepts both of options?

Comment: [A-Za-z]?\-?[A-Za-z]?

Comment: Works but now accepts numbers too which isnt supposed to :(

Comment: Try this: ^[A-Za-z]+\-?[A-Za-z]+$

Comment: this wont work in cases like `something-something-somthing`

Answer (score 0):

Does this pattern work for you?

```
^([A-Za-z]+-)+[A-Za-z]+$
```

Matches

```
Something-Something
Something-Something-Something
S-o-m-e-t-h-i-n-g
```

Does not match

```
-Something
Something-
Something-Something-
Something
```

Comment: Works but, it has to accept SomethingSomething pattern too, but this only accepts something-something, how can i make it do both?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex

```
^[^-]([a-zA-z-]*)[^-]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.   You didn't specify if the dash was required or not required.  I assume the dash was optional.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                "Something-something", 
                "-Something",
                "SomethingSomething-",
                "something-something-somthing",
                "1234"
            };

            string pattern = @"^([A-Za-z]+[-\s]?[A-Za-z]+)+$";

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input : '{0}', Match : '{1}'", input, Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern) ? "Yes" : "No");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }

}
```